# Horizontal LinearLayout with HorizontalScrollView. ImageView after ScrollView gone

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a Horizontal LinearLayout that have ImageView arrow left, HorizontalScrollView and ImageView arrow right. HorizontalScrollView have some ImageViews and I think it pushes the right arrow off the screen.

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/arrowLeft
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/arrowLeft"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="55dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:scrollbars="none">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/buttonToDoor"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/button_todoor" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/buttonWomen"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/button_women" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/buttonCommerce"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/button_commerce" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/buttonPause"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/button_pause" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/buttonTrunk"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/button_trunk" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/buttonSnack"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/button_snack" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/buttonSmoke"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/button_smoke" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/buttonWifi"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/button_wifi" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/buttonPackage"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/button_package" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </HorizontalScrollView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/arrowRight"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/rightArrow"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Image: [image]

How could I show the right arrow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the width of the HorizontalScrollView to 0dip and add to the attribute weight with value of 1

```
 <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android?layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="55dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:scrollbars="none">
```

This will make it fill all space available not ocuppied by other views (the arrows)

Answer (score 1):

You can also achieve it by using Relative layout as a parent layout instead of Linear Layout , update your code as following:-

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/arrowLeft"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/arrowLeft"
             android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
              android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/arrowLeft"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/arrowRight"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/buttonToDoor"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/button_todoor" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/buttonWomen"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/button_women" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/buttonCommerce"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/button_commerce" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/buttonPause"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/button_pause" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/buttonTrunk"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/button_trunk" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/buttonSnack"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/button_snack" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/buttonSmoke"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/button_smoke" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/buttonWifi"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/button_wifi" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/buttonPackage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/button_package" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/arrowRight"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/arrowLeft"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simply weight-property of xml...
just paste this code in your xml....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/arrowLeft"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/arrowLeft" />

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scrollbars="none" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/buttonToDoor"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/buttonWomen"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/buttonCommerce"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/buttonPause"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/buttonTrunk"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/buttonSnack"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/buttonSmoke"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/buttonWifi"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/buttonPackage"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/arrowRight"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/rightArrow" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```